# Parse and swift relational query

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have the following Parse backend for a fantasy football style app:

```
Class: _Users
standard columns

Class: Leagues
objectID
leagueName (String)
chairman (pointer to _User who created the league)

Class: LeagueMembers
objectID
memberID (pointer to _User)
leagueID (pointer to _Leagues objectId)
```

I want to display a list of leagues that a given user is a member of (they can be member of multiple leagues).
What swift code can I use to perform a query which searches "LeagueMembers" for all records that the currentUser is a member of, and with that result, obtain the leagueID (from "LeagueMembers") and then fetch the leagueName from "Leagues" based on the leagueID?
I have tried code similar to:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "LeagueMembers")

    query.includeKey("memberID")

    query.whereKey("memberID", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

...
```

but I would then need to conduct another query based on the results to fetch the League Name from "Leagues"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eager load the foreign key "Leagues" like you have eager loaded the Users FK.

`query.includeKey("leagueID")`

Then you should be able to access all properties of League pointer.

Comment: Done :) I think anyway!